# Submit form in Image onclick event and handle submission in PHP

Tags: php, javascript, forms

I'm submitting a form in JavaScript inside the onclick event of an image, the problem is how to know in PHP that i'm coming from the image submission?

```
if(isset(??))
{
  //submission code
}
```

Note: the form action is `$PHP_MYSELF`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could perhaps place a hidden field in your form and test on that.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're submitting a form, why not check for a form submit in PHP using:

```
if(isset($_POST))
{
    //do code
}
```

Comment: if I do this, the page keep refreshing for some reason it enters this statement every time..

Comment: What code are you executing when you go into if(isset($_POST)){} ?

Comment: I delete a record from database then refresh the page to filter the list i have.. it always refreshing because the if statement is always true

Comment: I use location.href of javascript inside PHP echo